# why cant i take * as a command line input n python(ubuntu linux)?

Tags: python, python-2.x

when the variable operation is printed, i get the script name itself.
*(asterisk) isn't being accepted as a command line argument.

```
from sys import argv
script,operation = argv
print "your script name is %s" % script
print "you have choosen to perform the following opertion : %s" % operation
string = "enter the first operand  "
a = int(raw_input(string))
b = int(raw_input("enter the second operand  "))
if (operation == "addition" or operation == "+"):
    print "the addition of %d and %d is %d" % (a,b,a+b)
elif (operation == "subtraction" or operation == "-"):
    print "the subtraction of %d and %d is %d" % (a,b,a-b)
elif (operation == "multiplication" or operation == '*'):
    print "the multiplication of %d and %d is %d" % (a,b,a*b)
elif (operation == "division" or operation == "/"):
    print "the division of %d by %d is %d" % (a,b,a/b)`
```

Comment: The asterisk symbol is expanded by the shell. In order to prevent expansion, you must quote it, for example: `python calc.py 2 '*' 2`

Comment: Your python code works for me, I ran it like this:  `python gash.py '*'`

Comment: thank you.it worked as you said.what does the shell expand the asterisk to?